# How notebook sends code to Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using a notebook environment to try out some commands against Spark. Can someone explain how the overall flow works when we run a cell from the notebook? In a notebook environment which component acts as the driver?

Also, can we call the code snippets we run from a notebook as a "Spark Application", or we call a code snippet "Spark Application" only when we use spark-submit to submit it to spark? Basically, I am trying to find out what qualifies a "Spark Application".

Answer (score 0):

Notebook environment like Zeppelin creates a `SparkContext` during first execution of cell. Once a `SparkContext` is created all further cell executions are submitted to the same `SparkContext` which was created earlier.

A driver program is started based on whether you're using spark cluster in standalone mode or cluster mode where a resource manager is managing you're spark cluster. So In case of standalone mode driver program is started on host where the notebook is running. And in case of cluster mode it will be started on one of the node in the cluster.

You can consider a each running `SparkContext` on cluster as a different Application. Notebooks like Zeppelin provide capability to share same `SparkContext` for all cell across all notebooks or you can even configure it to be created per notebook.

Most of the notebooks internally calls spark-submit only.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. Is it that Zeppelin has a server program that hosts the notebook UI? When a user runs a cell, the browser will submit the request to Zepplin server and internally the server makes a spark-submit call?

Comment: @OverlapToSky You're right.. Zeppelin has a server program which internally does spark-submit.